# Error getting time difference in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting below errors while trying to get a time difference in postgres. Can someone please help me to solve it?

```
db=> SELECT DATEDIFF(((m.message -> 'header') -> 'timestamp')  #>> '{}',((m.message -> 'header') -> 'timestamp')  #>> '{}')
FROM "RawMessages" m;
ERROR:  function datediff(text, text) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT DATEDIFF(((m.message -> 'header') -> 'timestamp')  #>...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

```
db=> SELECT (((m.message -> 'header') -> 'timestamp')  #>> '{}' - ((m.message -> 'header') -> 'timestamp')  #>> '{}')
FROM "RawMessages" m;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown - jsonb
LINE 1: ...(m.message -> 'header') -> 'timestamp')  #>> '{}' - ((m.mess...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

```
db=> SELECT ((m.message -> 'header') -> 'timestamp')  #>> '{}'
FROM "RawMessages" m;

         ?column?         
--------------------------
 2021-07-20T17:38:01.214Z
 2021-07-20T17:38:02.544Z
 2021-07-20T18:39:01.368Z
 2021-07-20T18:39:02.270Z
 2021-07-20T18:40:01.574Z
 2021-07-20T18:40:02.581Z
 2021-07-20T17:38:03.629Z
 2021-07-20T18:40:03.654Z
 2021-07-20T17:37:02.845Z
(9 rows)
```

I want to get time difference between those two dates stored in json.

Comment: There is no `DATEDIFF` function in Postgres. A cursory look at the available functions would have revealed that :[Date functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html). Just subtract the values.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for your response, I have update the post to add the result when I tried to subtract two values.

Comment: You don't show the actual values, but I'm guessing they are timestamp formatted strings. In which case you will need to cast them to timestamp: `select '2021-07-21 08:21'::timestamp;`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sorry, Actual values are stored in json object but above code returns `"2021-07-20T18:39:01.368Z"` from the table

Comment: Looking at the error shows this: `operator does not exist: unknown - jsonb` so it looks like you are not actually retrieving what you think are. First get the query to return the correct values, timestamp strings I assume, then work on doing the datetime math.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the post again with result from db

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT age((((m.message -> 'header') -> 'timestamp')  #>> '{}')::TIMESTAMP,(((m.message -> 'header') -> 'timestamp')  #>> '{}')::TIMESTAMP) FROM "RawMessages" m;
```

It worked for me.